# Is it legal to access a field of a returned union without a variable?

Tags: c, unions

I have a function returning a `union` type. Is it allowed by the standard (C99) to access a field of a returned value directly from the call without copying the value to a variable. Here an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
union thinga { int integ; char arr[4]; };

union thinga f(void)
{
  union thinga t = {.integ = 1};
  return t;
}
int main(void)
{
   printf("thinga is %d\n", f().integ);
}
```

Is the call with field `f().integ` allowed? In my example it's a `union` but the issue is the same for `struct`.
I ask the question, because I remember vividly that gcc 3.3 on Solaris  didn't like this construct and would warn like hell. Its problem was that it had to generate internally an invisible variable to be able to access the field of the `struct` or the `union`. Newer compilers seem not to mind the construct but I would like to know if there is a hidden catch (i.e. `undefined bevaviour` that I didn't think of.

EDIT: Ok it looks like my contrived example is a bit too simple and as commenter 2501 noticed by giving links to array decaying to pointer on out of scope objects, let's see if we are in the same situation if I change a bit my code.

```
 union thinga f(const char *val)
 {
   union thinga t = {.integ = 0};
   t.arr[0] = val[0];
   return t;
 }

 int main(void)
 {
     printf(" thinga.integ=%d .arr=%s\n", f("1").integ, f("1").arr);
 }
```

is this case the same as given in [arrays that are not lvalues and sequence point restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759295/arrays-that-are-not-lvalues-and-sequence-point-restriction/25759612#25759612) and [Undefined behavior: when attempting to access the result of function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755628/undefined-behavior-when-attempting-to-access-the-result-of-function-call/13755846#13755846) ? (the value returned are obviously impementation dependend (endiannes) but that is not the issue here).

Comment: Apparently the function always returns an `int`. So why using a `union`?

Comment: You might be surprised if you use `arr` member: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759295/arrays-that-are-not-lvalues-and-sequence-point-restriction/25759612#25759612 It seems ub in C99:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755628/undefined-behavior-when-attempting-to-access-the-result-of-function-call/13755846#13755846

Comment: Just a contrived example for the question. In my real  project the union has 3 different fields that are accessed differently in different modules. There would be no point in over complexifying the example.

Comment: @2501: C standard is C11, not C99. Do you have any idea how that is with C11? How do you mean that anyway? The function returns a `union`. The member-operator `.` then is applied like to a named union variable.

Comment: @Olaf OP is asking about C99. For C11, see temporary lifetime in the second link.

Comment: @2501: OP asks how this is in the standard, which would be C11, not C99. Maybe he has the wrong assumption C99 still is the standard. The C tag also is clearly referencing the C standard, not some older version. That's what the c99, etc. tags are for. He should clarify.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter The second link explains this for both C99 and C11. IMO this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: "Is it allowed by **the** standard (C99)" - C standard is currently C11, not C99. Do you ask about the **previous** standard (which is C99) or do you mean the C standard (aka C11)?

Comment: @2501, yes, I should have read the link till the end before editing my question :-) It gives exactly the answer I needed. Could you make your comment as an answer so that I can give you the "right answer" points?

Comment: @Olaf I asked for C99, because that is officially what our project is supposed to be conformant with, but you're right that current standard is C11.

Comment: So just a small recommendation: Please don't use the term "the standard" when not asking about **the** standard like canceled versions.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter Please vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid and allowed by c standard and there is no undefined behavior in this code.

**EDIT:** For the snippet

```
 int main(void)
 {
     printf(" thinga.integ=%d .arr=%s\n", f("1").integ, f("1").arr);
 }
```

`f("1").arr` is referencing `arr` element of the union. Since `arr` is an array and as per C rule, in this context array will decay to pointer to its first element. Since `t` is local to the function (an automatic local variable and will no longer be exist once function return), accessing `arr` elements will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is it thread safe on Linux platform?

Comment: @LPs: I would expect it is as thread-safe as the long way using a named variable in-between.

Comment: @Olaf thx. I was asking that because of I had problems with a old compiler/OS (introlne) where struct and unions was returned in a common area.

Comment: @LPs; If `thinga` is private to each thread then there would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just identical to

```
printf("thinga is %d\n", (union thinga) {.integ = 1}.integ);
```

, which is obviously well-defined.